# Why does "this" refer to the parent class although a child class object calls the method?

Tags: java, inheritance, this

I think I did not understand something related to Inheritance or the this statement.
If I execute a method of a parent class, which calls another function implemented in the child class,
this refers to the function of the parent class although the Object executing the parent's class function is a child class object.

For example:

Parent Class Methods

```java
public BookingConfirmation templateMethod(BigDecimal value) {
        try {
            Boolean authenticate = this.authenticate();
            if (!authenticate)
                // TODO Write own Exception for this Case
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Das Konto wurde nicht erfolgreich authentifiziert!");

            System.out.println(this.getClass().toString());

            this.bookTransaction(new BigDecimal("100"));
            BookingConfirmation bookingConfirmation = this.createBookingConfirmation();
            return bookingConfirmation;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

protected BookingConfirmation createBookingConfirmation() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet");
    }
```

Child Class Implementation:

```java
protected BookingConfirmation createBookingConfirmation(BigDecimal value) {
        try {
            String title = "Überweisung von Konto " + this.id.toString() + " in der Höhe von " + value.toString() + " Euro";
            BookingConfirmation bookingConfirmation = new BookingConfirmation(title);

            return bookingConfirmation;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `If I cast a method of a parent class`, this doesn't make any sense. You can't cast a method. Would you please rephrase your question?

Comment: have you overridden the methods? `this` belongs to current class and `super` belongs to parent. No one can tell **what/how** unless you add implementation of parent, child

Comment: When you say "parent" and "child", do you mean *superclass* and *subclass*?

Comment: @khelwood yes, I do

Comment: This actually refers to the current object. Super refers to the superclass.

Comment: But remember that the current object is also an instance of the parent object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods in parent and child have different signatures

- In parent: `createBookingConfirmation()`
- In child: `createBookingConfirmation(BigDecimal)`

Thus, the method is not [overridden](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html), but [overloaded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) and as consequence

```
BookingConfirmation bookingConfirmation = this.createBookingConfirmation();
```

always calls the method in the parent class. A fix would be to give the parent class method a `BigDecimal` parameter.

If a method of a parent class is overridden by a method of the child class, the correct child-class method will be called at runtime. The underlying concept is known as [dynamic dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch).

---

To prevent these kinds of mishaps, we should always annotate methods that are meant to override methods of supertypes with [`@Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Override.html). The compiler will generate a compiler error if the annotated method does not override a method in at least one supertype.

---

A remark on the wording of the question: [As was pointed out by JCWasmx86 in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63645271/why-does-this-refer-to-the-parent-class-although-a-child-class-object-calls-th/63645335#comment112545917_63645271), one cannot cast a method. What one can cast is a variable.

Comment: Ah, thanks that solved my problem. Forgot to annotate my methods and didn't know I can't overwrite a method if the params are different, thanks.